# PHP - Trying to re-write a file and it's leaving blank spaces

Tags: php, fwrite

Hello i have an issue when re-writting a file:

```
static function Remove($plate){

    $_parkedlist=parking::Read();
    $_remove = false;
    $_stillparkedlist = array();

    foreach($_parkedlist as $_car){

        if($_car[0] == $plate){

            $_firsttime = $_car[1];
            $_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $_timelapse = strtotime($_now) - strtotime($_firsttime);


            $_topay = $_timelapse * 10;

            echo "$_topay <br>";

            $_remove = true;


        } else {

            $_stillparkedlist [] = $_car;

        }
    }

    if ($_remove == true){

        $mifile = fopen('parked.txt',"w");

        foreach($_stillparkedlist as $_car){    

            if($_car[0]!=""){

                    $_line = $_car[0]."=>".$_car[1]."\n";       
                    fwrite($mifile,$_line);
            }

        }

        fclose($mifile);
    }
}
```

The original file is like this:

```
234FSC=>2016-09-07 17:06:23
JAG823=>2016-09-07 17:06:15
706KHB=>2016-09-07 17:06:15
980GHB=>2016-09-07 17:06:15
```

The  first time i remove it adds blank spaces (Removed 706KHB)

```
234FSC=>2016-09-07 17:06:23

JAG823=>2016-09-07 17:06:15

980GHB=>2016-09-07 17:06:15
```

If i remove again it starts showing "Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...\parking.php" and the  file looks like this

```
234FSC=>2016-09-07 17:06:23

=>
JAG823=>2016-09-07 17:06:15

=>
980GHB=>2016-09-07 17:06:15

=>
```

I have tried all i could find but this is still happening even with the   if($_car[0]!="") and isset($_car[0]!)

How can i re-write without this error?

Comment: I don't really get what you're trying to achieve. What exactly are you trying to rewrite this file into?

Comment: I'm  supossed to remove a plate register calculate the parking fee and leave  all the other parked cars in the file.

Comment: The text lines in `$_stillparkedlist` already have the newline character at the end but an another `."\n"` is added before `fwrite()`

Comment: markeful that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that each line is read from the file with a newline already attached to it.

So when you execute this line

```
$_line = $_car[0]."=>".$_car[1]."\n";
```

It is adding another newline so instead do

```
$_line = $_car[0]."=>".$_car[1];
```

So you are not adding another newline

Comment: Thanks this works! I'll accept your answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that `fwrite` already adds a `PHP_EOL`, so remove the extra `"\n"`

However perhaps you should restructure the array to make things easier:

```
static function Remove($plate){
  $data = parking::Read();  

  // restructuring happens here.
  foreach($data as $car){
    $list[$car[0]] = $car[1];
  }

  foreach($list as $key => $val){
    if($key == $plate){
        $now     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $elapsed = strtotime($now) - strtotime($val);
        $price   = $elapsed * 10;

        echo $price;
        unset($list[$key]); // *poof*, removed the found car from the list.
        break;
    }
  }

  // if the new generated list is smaller then the original one, update.
  if(sizeof($list) != sizeof($data)){
    $fh = fopen('parked.txt',"w");
    foreach($list as $key => $val){
      fwrite($fh,"$key=>$plate");
    }
    fclose($fh);
   }
 }
```

This code also has the quirk that it automatically removes duplicate entry's.